# Node.js process exiting in the middle, with no error (using streams)

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, node-streams

I'm writing a Lambda function which is given a list of text files on S3, and concatenates them together, and then zips that resulting file. For some reason, the function is bombing out in the middle of the process, with no errors.

The payload sent to the Lambda func looks like this:

```
{
  "sourceFiles": [
    "s3://bucket/largefile1.txt",
    "s3://bucket/largefile2.txt"
  ],
  "destinationFile": "s3://bucket/concat.zip",
  "compress": true,
  "omitHeader": false,
  "preserveSourceFiles": true
}
```

The scenarios in which this function works totally fine:

1. The two files are small, and `compress === false`
2. The two files are small, and `compress === true`
3. The two files are large, and `compress === false`

If I try to have it compress two large files, it quits in the middle. The concatenation process itself works fine, but when it tries to use `zip-stream` to add the stream to an archive, it fails.

The two large files together are 483,833 bytes. When the Lambda function fails, it reads either 290,229 or 306,589 bytes (it's random) then quits.

This is the main entry point of the function:

```
const packer = require('zip-stream');
const S3 = require('aws-sdk/clients/s3');
const s3 = new S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });
const { concatCsvFiles } = require('./csv');
const { s3UrlToParts } = require('./utils');

function addToZip(archive, stream, options) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    archive.entry(stream, options, (err, entry) => {
      console.log('entry done', entry);
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve(entry);
    });
  });
}

export const handler = async event => {
  /**
   * concatCsvFiles returns a readable stream to pass to either the archiver or
   * s3.upload.
   */
  let bytesRead = 0;

  try {
    const stream = await concatCsvFiles(event.sourceFiles, {
      omitHeader: event.omitHeader,
    });
    stream.on('data', chunk => {
      bytesRead += chunk.length;
      console.log('read', bytesRead, 'bytes so far');
    });
    stream.on('end', () => {
      console.log('this is never called :(');
    });
    const dest = s3UrlToParts(event.destinationFile);
    let archive;

    if (event.compress) {
      archive = new packer();

      await addToZip(archive, stream, { name: 'concat.csv' });
      archive.finalize();
    }

    console.log('uploading');
    await s3
      .upload({
        Body: event.compress ? archive : stream,
        Bucket: dest.bucket,
        Key: dest.key,
      })
      .promise();

    console.log('done uploading');

    if (!event.preserveSourceFiles) {
      const s3Objects = event.sourceFiles.map(s3Url => {
        const { bucket, key } = s3UrlToParts(s3Url);

        return {
          bucket,
          key,
        };
      });

      await s3
        .deleteObjects({
          Bucket: s3Objects[0].bucket,
          Delete: {
            Objects: s3Objects.map(s3Obj => ({ Key: s3Obj.key })),
          },
        })
        .promise();
    }

    console.log('## Never gets here');

    // return {
    //   newFile: event.destinationFile,
    // };
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.code) {
      throw new Error(e.code);
    }

    throw e;
  }
};
```

And this is the concatenation code:

```
import MultiStream from 'multistream';
import { Readable } from 'stream';
import S3 from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3';
import { s3UrlToParts } from './utils';

const s3 = new S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });

/**
 * Takes an array of S3 URLs and returns a readable stream of the concatenated results
 * @param {string[]} s3Urls Array of S3 URLs
 * @param {object} options Options
 * @param {boolean} options.omitHeader Omit the header from the final output
 */
export async function concatCsvFiles(s3Urls, options = {}) {
  // Get the header so we can use the length to set an offset in grabbing files
  const firstFile = s3Urls[0];
  const file = s3UrlToParts(firstFile);
  const data = await s3
    .getObject({
      Bucket: file.bucket,
      Key: file.key,
      Range: 'bytes 0-512', // first 512 bytes is pretty safe for header size
    })
    .promise();
  const streams = [];
  const [header] = data.Body.toString().split('\n');

  for (const s3Url of s3Urls) {
    const { bucket, key } = s3UrlToParts(s3Url);

    const stream = s3
      .getObject({
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: key,
        Range: `bytes=${header.length + 1}-`, // +1 for newline char
      })
      .createReadStream();
    streams.push(stream);
  }

  if (!options.omitHeader) {
    const headerStream = new Readable();
    headerStream.push(header + '\n');
    headerStream.push(null);
    streams.unshift(headerStream);
  }

  const combinedStream = new MultiStream(streams);
  return combinedStream;
}
```

Comment: first of all, use `process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => console.log(err))`  to see if there is something wrong, if nothing happened, I assume that this proccess was killed because of OOM.

Comment: OOM, as in, out of memory? The whole point of streaming is that it takes up minimal memory. I don't think that's it.

Comment: No uncaught exceptions, just checked.

Comment: `archive.finalize();` I think this will drain the stream to buffer that takes memory, and default lambda memory limit is 128mb, try concat without compress

Comment: I've set the memory to 2GB, so memory is not the problem. And as I mentioned in my post, concat without zip compression works totally fine.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. The problem was actually with the `zip-stream` library. Apparently it doesn't work well with S3 + streaming. I tried `yazl` and it works perfectly.